# RemoteApp and Transparency

Tags: transparency, rdp, remoteapp

I use custom application as a Windows RemoteApp. The window of this application does not have a frame. Also the window is transparent in both ways: transparent background and transparent mouse input. This window places above all windows and indicate some changing information.

The problem is that when application works as a RemoteApp the window is created without `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag. As a result the window is not transparent for mouse input. There is no such problem if application run locally.

Down below presented the pictures of application's window flags:

- [Window flags of application running locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZCrR.png)
- [Window flags of application running as a RemoteApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iafz0.png)

I tried to configure my rdp file with [different settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files), but I didn't find something usefull.

Anyway my rdp file looks like that:

```
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
devicestoredirect:s:*
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectdrives:i:1
session bpp:i:32
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
server port:i:3389
allow font smoothing:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
audiocapturemode:i:1
gatewayusagemethod:i:0
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
gatewaycredentialssource:i:0
full address:s:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
alternate shell:s:||MyApp
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||MyApp
remoteapplicationname:s:MyApp
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:
workspace id:s:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
use redirection server name:i:1
loadbalanceinfo:s:tsv://MS Terminal Services Plugin.1.QuickSessionCollection
```

Any idea what can be done to make the window transparent for mouse input when application run as RemoteApp?

Comment: What OS are you using ? I also had a problem that a should be transparent region of a window is not transparent. I am using Server 2022.

Comment: I use the following OS:
1. Server: Windows Server 2016 Standart
2. Client: Windows 10 Pro
3. mstsc.exe: 10.0.19041.1266

Do you have any idea to solve it out?

Comment: Thanks. My problem seems different. It happens only when using RemoteApp on Server 2022 (Server 2016 is OK). The appearance of a supposedly transparent/half-transparent window becomes opaque when run as RemoteApp on Server 2022. I submitted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421726/window-cannot-be-made-transparent-half-transparent-when-invoked-as-remoteapp-on